# Checkout Link is not removing

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

I am trying to remove Checkout link but it's not removing.

my code is:

**magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\layout\local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>

        <reference name="top.links">           
            <remove name="checkout.links"></remove>
        </reference>

        </default>

</layout>
```

can anyone tell me how can I do?

thanks.

Comment: Is the theme you're using set to be loaded in the Magento config, or is the local.xml the only file in your theme so far?

Answer (score 1):

Just Refer checkout.xml

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
</default>
```

**You have to give correct name to remove the link or block**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>

            <reference name="top.links">           
                <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
            </reference>

            </default>

    </layout>
```

Comment: this is not working..

Comment: refer your checkout module xml file
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. I tried to remove it with local.xml, but I could figure out how to remove ONLY the "checkout" button, and not the "Cart" button (which tells you how many items you have in the cart.)

I ended up hiding it with CSS:

```
#header .top-link-checkout {display: none;}
```

For anyone interested in finding a true solution, the links are rendered by this template:
frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml

The links are added to the menu by this block
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php
(See function "addCheckoutLink")

I can't see any way to "removeCheckoutLink" and thought that the CSS solution was easier than modifying core for something so simple.